# Convert.ChangeType (Error: Object must implement IConvertible) when Dynamically Convert object to IList fails Why?

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

I am using the `Convert.ChangeType(object, Type)` method to convert objects to their types. It has worked great. It works just fine when I try to convert an `Object` (of type `List<string>`) back to a `List<string>`. However, when I try to convert an `Object` to be a `IList<string>`, it fails.

Issue: When I try to convert an object which should be of type `IList`, to `IList`, it fails with error message 'Object must implement IConvertible'

```
IList<string> myList = new List<string>();
object myObject = myList;
Type myType = typeOf(IList<string>);
Convert.ChangeType(myObject, myType);
```

Anyone know how to successfully convert an object back to its original type of IList ... Or does anyone know how to convert an object which was originally an IList to a List? Either would work.

Comment: Your statement _" It works just fine when I try to convert an `Object` (which was previously of type `List<string>`) back to a `List<string>`."_ indicates the misunderstanding you have.  If an object is a `List<string>` it remains a `List<string>`, even if you store a reference to it in a variable of type `object`.  There's no need to _Change its type_; the type remains the same.

Comment: It is an IList, not a List. There is no misunderstanding. Struggled with this too long for it to be a misunderstanding. Mainly posting this so others won't struggle with this as well.

Comment: It's both an `List<string>` and an `IList<string>`.  My point has nothing to do with `List` or `IList`.  If I create an object: `object o = new List<int>();`.  That object is a `List<int>`, an `IList<int>`, an `object`, an `IEnumerable`, etc.  If I store a reference to that object in a variable of any of those types (`IEnumerable ie = (IEnumerable)o;`), it doesn't change the underlying nature (/type) of the object.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. The object was never Not a list. Might have been a better way to word the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The below code solved my issue:

```
// Initial objects (the original IList object ended up as an object plus a Type)
IList<string> stringList = new List<string>(); // dont' have access to this form of the object
object myObject = stringList;
Type originalType = typeof(List<string>);

// Converting object to a List<string>
if(originalType.Name.StartsWith("IList"))
{
  Type myNewList = typeof(List<>);
  Type typeInIList = originalType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
  Type aStringListType = myNewList.MakeGenericType(typeInIList);
  dynamic newStringList = Convert.ChangeType(myObject, aStringListType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `Convert.ChangeType`, or `dynamic`. If the object is actually an `IList<string>`, you can use an `is` type pattern to check it:

```
if (myObject is IList<string> list) {
    // "list" is the converted list
} else {
    // conversion fails
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For what I am doing with the object later on in the code, I do need to convert it back to a List.